# Important typo in Schwartz's QFT: Incorrect spinor solutions leading to wrong charge conjugation properties

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, spinors, textbook-erratum

Eq 11.18 in Schwartz's book reads:
$$u_{\uparrow}=\sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
u_{\downarrow}=\sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}
v_{\uparrow}=\sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
v_{\downarrow}=\sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}.\tag{11.18}
$$

This is physically incorrect since to construct the correct Dirac field we must have:$$J_zv_s(p)=-s\ v_s(p)$$

for details see this post:[A problematic equation for Dirac field:$[\psi,\hat{J_z}]=J_z\psi+i(x{\partial \psi\over\partial y}-y{\partial\psi\over\partial x})$ How is this true?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/783925)
(This post iteslef is an unsolved problem but it should justify the equation above)

The correct result should be:
$$u_{\uparrow}=\sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
u_{\downarrow}=\sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}
v_{\downarrow}=\sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
v_{\uparrow}=\sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}.\tag{11.18'}
$$

This is also the result in Peskin's and Srednicki's textbook, which are both derived in Weyl representation.

Also, Schwartz's book has an unconventional, if not wrong property of charge conjugation ------ it flips spin. (see eq 11.44) Technically, the form of charge conjugation in the textbook is not wrong. Once the correct spinors are used, the spin won't flip under charge conjugation.

Comment: "This is physically incorrect since to construct the correct Dirac field we must have: $J_sv_s(p) = - s v_s(p)$. Why MUST we have this?

Comment: @Prahar you can check the link I provided for why it must hold. The post itself is an unsolved problem but it should provide enough insight into why $J_zv_s(p)=-s\ v_s(p)$ must be true.

Comment: That question seems unrelated. I'm just saying that there is no reason that it MUST be true. These are conventions and different textbooks employ different choices for these conventions. If you think that there is an inconsistency in Schwartz's book then you should explain that carefully.

Comment: Did you check the [Errata](https://schwartzqft.fas.harvard.edu/corrections)? Each of the 5 printings?

Comment: @Prahar, yes, it MUST be true as you may check more carefully. If this won't convince you, then the corresponding Feynman rules and the result for scattering amplitudes will be distinctively different, indicating that one of them must be wrong.

Comment: @Qmechanic, I checked, not on the list.